# Stucked with ruby or { || } operator with if condition

Tags: ruby

My code is

```
if @site.Name != ("B.A.P." || "Cir." || "10th")
  do this if part
else
  do this else part
end
```

`if @site.name = "B.A.P"` is working fine but for others two it's not working properly. I also used one more syntax which is:

```
if ["B.A.P." , "Cir." , "10th"].include? (@site.Name)
```

Again facing the same problem. Can any one suggest me proper way to implement logical `or operator with if condition?

Comment: Second syntax is correct. I am not sure about the first one. Check the value of your `@site.Name` variable to confirm things.

Comment: Second one is also not working. i checked value of    @site.name  value belongs to these three only.

Comment: check value of `@site.Name` before `if` and add it to question also using downcase for column names is good practice use `name` instead if `Name`

Comment: BTW, general ruby style prefers `@site.name` instead of `@site.Name`.  Capital letters are usually reserved for constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second version should work

```
1.9.3p194 :027 > ["B.A.P." , "Cir." , "10th"].include? "Cir."
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :028 > ["B.A.P." , "Cir." , "10th"].include? "10th"
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :029 > ["B.A.P." , "Cir." , "10th"].include? "B.A.P."
 => true
```

Check if there are any terminators etc in @site.Name

In your first version  this is what happens

```
1.9.3p194 :033 > ("B.A.P." || "Cir." || "10th")
 => "B.A.P." # always evaluates to first arg
```

For 1st version use this

```
if @site.Name == "B.A.P." || @site.Name == "Cir." || @site.Name == "10th"
```

or in more rubyish way

```
@site.Name.eql? "B.A.P." or @site.Name.eql? "Cir." or @site.Name.eql? "10th"
```

I will go with array include version. :)

Comment: `("B.A.P." || "Cir." || "10th")` always evaluates to `"B.A.P."` -- the second part of your answer makes no sense.

Comment: when i am doing @site.name getting output like "B.A.P." or if i am using inspect getting output like "\"B.A.P. \"" where is the problen i am not able to identify

Comment: What is 'more rubyish way' in second one?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier it is expressed in OOP terms

Comment: `==` is also OOP term, see Smalltalk.

Answer (score 1):

The first version works the way you'd speak in English, but it's not how most programming languages work.  Instead, you'd have to do:

```
if @site.Name != "B.A.P." && @site.Name != "Cir." && @site.Name != "10th"
```

If you're actually testing to see if `@site.Name` *does* equal one of those, which is what it looks like from your second version, you'd do:

```
if @site.Name == "B.A.P." || @site.Name == "Cir." || @site.Name == "10th"
```

I prefer your second version, which is perfectly valid.  (Assuming, again, that your condition is that `@site.Name` *is* equal to one of those three values.)  If it's not working for you, it seems likely that you mean `@site.name` rather than `@site.Name` (capitalization matters).

Comment: +1, you're the first one which saw that the first logic (negative with `!=`) is different from the second logic (affirmative with `include?`).

Comment: when i am doing @site.name getting output like "B.A.P." or if i am using inspect getting output like "\"B.A.P.\"" where is the problen i am not able to identify

Comment: Thanks Darshan Actually its developed code and they have done in this way so i am bounded to use same convention.

Answer (score 0):

Your pieces of code turns the question ambiguous.

In the first part, you used `!=`. So, if you want to see whether `@site.Name` *is none of* "B.A.P.", "Cir." or "10th", the second part must be in negative form, i.e.:

```
unless ["B.A.P." , "Cir." , "10th"].include? (@site.Name)
```

I'd use that.

Comment: when i am doing @site.name getting output like "B.A.P." or if i am using inspect getting output like "\"B.A.P.\"" where is the problen i am not able to identify

Comment: About that you must ask a new question.